# Answer flag declined because of the age of the answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

[Do antistatic bags have conductive interior, exterior or both?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/do-antistatic-bags-have-conductive-interior-exterior-or-both)

This is the Question with the answer that I flagged.

I came upon this question by way of a link from a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/770685/is-it-safe-to-power-on-a-motherboard-outside-of-its-case#comment1000350_770690) on an answer to a question on the Superuser site.

I flagged this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/6139/18475) because it doesn't answer the question ***(to any degree)***, and this was the response that I received on the decline:

> Declined - This is a 3.5 year old question, not worth revisiting now.

How is it not worth revisiting? Simple vote to delete would be sufficient to get rid of this "non-answer."

Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and deleted it.

Part of the concern is to discourage going through old questions looking for trouble. When you go back 3-4 years, to the infancy of the site, you see a lot of behavior that would not be allowed now because people were unfamiliar with the format. Also, rules have changed over the years. Finding things to flag in old questions isn't that hard, but usually it's not a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: agreed. and I won't do any digging here mostly because it isn't my area of expertise.  :)

Comment: Isn't there value in cleaning up old posts to avoid misleading new users about the accepted format? (Not saying we should start digging, but the occasional flag from the archives ought to be valuable.)